# Traveling Swiss Rail with a Eurail pass — is there still a need to purchase supplements to travel from Disentis/Mustér to Andermatt?

Tags: switzerland, eurail

We have a 1st Class, Select Eurail Pass for Switzerland and I have seen the notice that the route from Disentis/Mustér over the pass to Andermatt costs extra, even with this pass. I also have seen recent notices that since the first of January, 2017, a Eurail pass will cover the entire cost of the trip.

Has anyone had recent experience with using a Eurail Pass on this journey and is there a charge? We hope to hop off the Bernina Express northbound to Chur at Reichenau and transfer to the next westbound train to get to Andermatt. Will we have to take the time to buy (if this is a ticketing stop) the supplement to the fare, or can it be purchased on the train from the conductor?

Comment: Just to confirm. You bought a pass last year for this year and want to know whether it's going to cover the stretch from Disentis to Andermatt according to the new rule or whether the old rule applies because you bought it before the 1st of January?

Comment: The Eurail Pass was purchased in December, 2017. It will not be activated until travel in mid-March, 2017.

Answer (score 3):

I am still not 100% sure what your question is, but I'll try to answer as best as I can.

The stretch from Disentis to Andermatt is operated by Matterhorn Gotthard Bahn. According to [their website](https://www.matterhorngotthardbahn.ch/en/winter/railway-information/discounts/), you will get 25% discount on trains with your Eurail pass. It is possible that this hasn't been updated yet, but I think this is unlikely, as the website below for the other train is maintained by the same company and is updated. The full price of this (before reduction) is CHF 37.20 for a 1st class ticket.

However, there is a special panoramic express train "Glacier Express", operated by the same company with a couple of connections every day. For that train they state [on their website](https://www.glacierexpress.ch/en/travel-planning/discounts/) that you can travel for free. However, this train has a [compulsory reservation charge](https://www.glacierexpress.ch/en/travel-planning/prices/) of CHF 13 during the winter months and CHF 23/33 during the summer months.

I wasn't able to find any information on whether you can buy the ticket for this specific stretch on the train. However in general this is not possible any more in Switzerland and you risk to be fined. Normally you can buy tickets online, but the online system doesn't seem to have the option for a 25% discount. If you don't have time to buy the ticket/reservation in Disentis however, you should be able to buy it at any other train station with a ticket office in Switzerland. (It doesn't need to be from the same train operator)